# How to obtain original XHR request with Sinon FakeXMLHttpRequest

Tags: sinon

Here's the example from docs:

```
{
    setUp: function () {
        this.xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
        var requests = this.requests = [];

        this.xhr.onCreate = function (xhr) {
            requests.push(xhr);
        };
    },

    tearDown: function () {
        this.xhr.restore();
    },

    "test should fetch comments from server" : function () {
        var callback = sinon.spy();
        myLib.getCommentsFor("/some/article", callback);
        assertEquals(1, this.requests.length);

        this.requests[0].respond(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                                 '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]');
        assert(callback.calledWith([{ id: 12, comment: "Hey there" }]));
    }
}
```

This works well however it doesn't allow me to inspect what my code actually sends using the `xhr.send()` call so not very useful to me.

Because I am unit testing in a node env I do not have a real XMLHttpRequest object so something like nock will not work.

Sinon seems like it might but I am not finding what I need - is there a way to see what the res.send() call actually sends instead of faking that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It is available by inspecting the `this.request[0].requestBody` element.

```
"test should fetch comments from server" : function () {
    var callback = sinon.spy();
    myLib.getCommentsFor("/some/article", callback);
    var body = JSON.parse(this.requests[0].requestBody);
    assert(body.XYX)...
}
```

Comment: what do you stub in for myLib.getCommentsFor?

Comment: This is a while back but I think `myLib.getCommentsFor?` was simply my API calling function. Some function that made an XHR request - in this case for comments for an article but really anything that makes a request. I didn't stub it - I use a real database for testing with fake testing data I load.